# App crashing while creating new activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, radio-button

I have an app that creates a new activity on click depending on which radio button was chosen. It works with option "3" but crashes with any other options.

Here is my class Polynomials:

```
public class Polynomials extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View polyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_poly, container, false);

        //layout
        RadioGroup rbg = (RadioGroup) polyView.findViewById(R.id.rBGPolyn);
        Button next = (Button) polyView.findViewById(R.id.btnNxt);
        final TextView checked = (TextView) polyView.findViewById(R.id.testpoly);
        RadioButton but3 = (RadioButton) polyView.findViewById(R.id.rb3);
        RadioButton but4 = (RadioButton) polyView.findViewById(R.id.rb4);
        RadioButton but5 = (RadioButton) polyView.findViewById(R.id.rb5);
        RadioButton but6 = (RadioButton) polyView.findViewById(R.id.rb6);
        RadioButton but7 = (RadioButton) polyView.findViewById(R.id.rb7);
        //RadioButton but8 = (RadioButton) polyView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton6);






        // reference to radio group
        final RadioGroup g = (RadioGroup)polyView.findViewById(R.id.rBGPolyn);





        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int selected = g.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton clickedButton=(RadioButton)polyView.findViewById(selected);
                checked.setText(""+clickedButton.getText());

                if(checked.getText().equals("3")){
                    b3clicked();
                }
                else {
                    if (checked.getText().equals("4")) {
                        b4clicked();
                    }
                    else {
                        if (checked.getText().equals("5")) {
                            b5clicked();
                        }
                        else {
                            if (checked.getText().equals("6")) {
                                b6clicked();
                            }
                            else {
                                if (checked.getText().equals("7")) {
                                    b7clicked();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }


            }




        });



        return polyView;
    }


   public void b3clicked(){
       Intent intent= new Intent(Polynomials.this.getActivity(), poly3.class);
      startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void b4clicked(){
        Intent intent= new Intent(Polynomials.this.getActivity(), poly4.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void b5clicked(){
        Intent intent= new Intent(Polynomials.this.getActivity(), poly5.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void b6clicked(){
        Intent intent= new Intent(Polynomials.this.getActivity(), poly6.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void b7clicked(){
        Intent intent= new Intent(Polynomials.this.getActivity(), poly7.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }


}
```

Function b3clicked works fine but others cause app to crash. Here is class poly3:

```
public class poly3 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_poly3);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_poly3, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And for comparison class poly4 which function b4clicked does not work:

```
public class poly4 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_poly4);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_poly4, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Here is activity_poly3:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.michniewicz.jan.mathcalcalpha.adapter.poly3">

<TextView android:text="3 terms" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here is activity_poly4:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.michniewicz.jan.mathcalcalpha.adapter.poly4">

<TextView android:text="4 terms" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Menu poly 3:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.michniewicz.jan.mathcalcalpha.adapter.poly3">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="never" />
```

And menu poly 4:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.michniewicz.jan.mathcalcalpha.adapter.poly4">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="never" />
```

I have just copied everything that was in poly 3 class or activity or menu and pasted to the next ones changing only number corresponding to class or activity.
Why is my function b4cliked not working?

Comment: How is it possible to write so much code without knowing how to use the debugger or logcat?

Comment: Have you added all the Activities to your manifest?